# Is there an MS Enterprise Library application block for Network Services

Tags: c#, networking, enterprise-library

So I have a simple service, has some sockets, takes requests sends back some results.

We want to make this a bit more enterprise friendly, allow configuration through Group Policy to be merged with local config, so I stumbled back across the ManageableConfigurationSource.

Now I'm thinking that it would be nice to make a wider use of the Enterprise Library, because it seems a right pain to jump in to it just to use core and the common configuration.

Are there application block(s) that provide "easy" access to a

- **"configurable SSL server"** from which to build your networking on top of? **Keyword Configurable.**
- ActiveMQ (MSMQ?)
- WMI

**Edit:**
What I am primarily interested in is an ability to configure through group policy, a somewhat mass distributed service.
Administrators don't seem to want to go to *hundreds* of machines and set the IP for the config on each one individually, or the name of the certificate and the store to find it in when it is distributed by group policy.

Sorry about the distraction - The service would use WMI for getting data from the local PC such as performance and events.  Not using WMI or MQ as the transport for our custom data. Application blocks for these are of secondary interest.

[MS PPT Pres I found helpful based on the answer about using WCF](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=6&ved=0CDsQFjAF&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.microsoft.com%2Fdownload%2Fb%2F2%2F2%2Fb22eb038-fa47-4f5e-ac70-5e17d8db55aa%2Fenterprise%2520library%25203.0%2520validation.ppt&rct=j&q=WCF%20ManageableConfigurationSource%20custom%20config&ei=frYCTdPCAYeC4Ab52PGSCg&usg=AFQjCNEC_QmBkfFxwLmEtvarzY_C_r15tw&sig2=lVWGgNosvojk3mc6NQ9k9w&cad=rja)

So there are some application blocks for exception handling and validation with WCF but no network configuration. Seeing [The ever so helpfuly named 'Write Less code and play more golf'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648712.aspx)

- `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.WCF`
- `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Integration.WCF`

**Edit:**

Say you had a simple config like this you needed to make to 100's of hosts.  Why woouldn't I push this common config through group policy rather than modify app.config for each host through some other method?

Sure I can do part of the work and push the certificates into the store through group policy, but I need to distribute to **LOTS** of hosts, and in some cases hosts may even change role and have policies so changed.
Be it for 1 or many configurations for different policies like dev/test/production.

```
<client>
    <endPoint address="tcp://Service1:1024" behaviorConfiguration="localhost" />
    <endPoint address="tcp://Service2:1024" behaviorConfiguration="secure-domain1" />
    <endPoint address="tcp://Service3:1099" behaviorConfiguration="secure-domain1" />
    <endPoint address="tcp://Service4:1024" behaviorConfiguration="secure-domain1" />
    <endPoint address="tcp://Service5:1024" behaviorConfiguration="secure-domain2" />
    <endPoint address="tcp://Service6:1048" behaviorConfiguration="secure-domain2" />
    <endPoint address="tcp://Service7:1024" behaviorConfiguration="secure-domain2" />
</client>
<behaviors>
    <behavior name="secure-domain1">
        <clientCredentials>
            <clientCertificate storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" findValue="Domain1"/>
            <serviceCertificate>
                <authentication certificateValidationMode="ChainTrust" trustedStoreLocation="LocalMachine"/>
            </serviceCertificate>
        </clientCredentials>
        <networking shortRetryInterval="300" shortRetryAttempts="5" longRetryInterval="1800"/>
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="secure-domain2">
        <clientCredentials>
            <clientCertificate storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" findValue="Domain2"/>
            <serviceCertificate>
                <authentication certificateValidationMode="ChainOrPeerTrust" trustedStoreLocation="LocalMachine"/>
            </serviceCertificate>
        </clientCredentials>
        <networking shortRetryInterval="600" shortRetryAttempts="2" longRetryInterval="3600"/>
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="localhost">
        <networking shortRetryInterval="60" shortRetryAttempts="3" longRetryInterval="600"/>
        <clientCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate>
                <authentication certificateValidationMode="None"/>
            </serviceCertificate>
        </clientCredentials>
    </behavior>
</behaviors>
```

Comment: Do you typically use Group Policy to modify text files?

Comment: Not personally, nor was it my plan.  If I was able to use ManageableConfigurationSource for instance this would merge the settings from the app.config file with settings from the policy section in the registry to take it from group policy or various other sources.

Comment: my point is that this isn't what Group Policy is for, and I've never heard of anyone even trying to do this in the past.

Comment: @John: Thankyou for your time and efforts in answering my queries, much appreciated.  To me this config is like various other already present in the application blocks and able to be stored in group policy, one such example would database settings.

Comment: but it's not using the Application Blocks. Not everything in the world uses them. I didn't even know this feature was there. I've never used Group Policy for a purpose like this, though I seem to recall it has some feature for being able to "publish" applications. If so, I'd just publish the config file along with the application.

Answer (score 2):

WCF is the answer to your question.

Comment: WCF seems to be aimed at Web Services SOA, soap etc., as opposed to some app running on the desktop or windows service that just happens to have network connectivity... I'll investigate more, but I'm not feeling this is what I was really after.  Maybe it should be SOA.

Comment: @John Saunders is right.  WCF nicely encapsulates pretty much all network communication,  whether it's a web service, console app, windows app, and it's exactly what you're looking for.  Your perception that is' mostly for SOA is probably based on your search results, which are skewed because SOA has been such an "in" thing over the last few years, so there are a slew of articles showing how to use WCF to simplify SOA.  WCF still acheives your goals, but your goals are not what's being hyped, so you have to look past the hype and search a little harder.

Comment: Added - try searching for "WCF MSMQ" and "WCF Winforms" to get good examples of how WCF works with those, for example.

Comment: @Greg: WCF is the intended platform for all communications. A common WCF scenario is a desktop application talking to a windows service using binary data over TCP/IP, named pipes or MSMQ.

Comment: Sorry I seem to have distracted the questions intent, and my first response here didn't help.  I'm interested in configuration and not having to go machine by machine to adjust app.config. This included various config tasks including networking.  I'll continue to look at the suggestions on WCF a lot to get through, but this didn't answer my config goal yet.

Comment: @Greg: I'm not sure how much of the configuration would change on a machine to machine basis. I don't know your situation, but why wouldn't every "desktop" use the same URL to talk to the service? Why wouldn't they all use the same set of named certificates, in the same store? Group policy could push the particular certificates required, no? Maybe you could ask another question to focus on this. Something like, "How to Minimize Per-Client Config when using WCF in a Desktop Application?"

Comment: @John: Exactly, regardless of whether these are client/server I want to push out settings for networking/WCF using group policy.  WCF modules don't appear to cover this, neither have I found prebuilt Enterprise Library module.  Am I missing the WCF Group policy settings option for `system.serviceModel` section?  Perhaps just expecting too much but really thought somebody else would have writting group policy config for WCF already.

Comment: @Greg: as I said, there is no need for group policy for configuring WCF. Which WCF settings would you like to use Group Policy to set?

Comment: Thanks John, I've edited the question with example WCF config section I want to push.